# Control lost focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, keyup

I have a form, and when I press a keyboard key over the form `Key_Up` event works fine, but when I press any button on `ToolStrip`, I lost Form forever and `Key_Up` event doesn't work anymore.

I want a solution that when I put the mouse pointer over `PictureBox` then give Form the focus, like VMware window.

```
private void frmMonitor_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyValue == 18)
        return;
     pc.PacketSystem.Send_KeyBoardEventPacket(e.KeyValue.ToString());
}
private void picSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     this.Focus();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out `PreviewKeyDown` handler and add it to your controls. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you have any other key events??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 private void picSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            this.Activate();
            this.KeyPreview=true;
}
```

thanks, Roman